# Titanium module imagefactory won't work

Tags: javascript, module, titanium, appcelerator

After several hours, and still not working image module, I hope for som help here.

I'm trying to install/use the imagefactory module.
1) I installed it globaly using Titanium studio (tried both from github and appcelerator) but it doesn't show upp when I look for modules in the terminal ('Titanium module'), or in my tiapp.xml when trying to include the module.

The plugin installs itself in the directory

```
Titanium/
    mobilesdk
    modules
    ti.imagefactory-stable <-- here
```

I tried to move the folder to the folders

```
Titanium/moduels/android/ti.imagefactory-stable
```

and

```
Titanium/modules/ios/ti.imagefactory-stable
```

Then it recognized the module, but then I got this error:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.4.1, Titanium SDK version 3.4.1.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2014, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=ti.imagefactory-stable version=ios platform=iphone     deploy-type=development path=/Users/username/Library/Application     Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/ti.imagefactory-stable/ios
[ERROR] :  Module ti.imagefactory-stable version 1.2.0 is missing library file: /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/iphone/ti.imagefactory-stable/ios/libti.imagefactory-stable.a
```

Any help is very appreciated since I'm kind of stuck right now... I also tried to install locally to the project without success.

Comment: I find installing module from [gitTio](http://gitt.io/) easiest. For imagefactory module see [this url](http://gitt.io/component/ti.imagefactory).

Comment: It worked! Thanks, please enter that as an answer so I can mark it as correct answer =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To install titanium modules and alloy widgets, now we have a package manager its [gitTio](http://gitt.io/).

gitTio can be installed via npm ( [more info on installing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gittio) ) using following command :

```
npm install -g gittio
```

Now we can search various modules/widgets available at [gitTio database](http://gitt.io/), like the ti.imagefactory module is available [here](http://gitt.io/component/ti.imagefactory).

Finally you can install the module using `gittio install` command form the root directory of your project. Example usage below :

```
gittio install ti.imagefactory
```