# custom maps for android and IOS on titanium

Tags: android, ios, maps, titanium

Is there a way to create costume maps for android and IOS in titanium Studio? I have tried with MapBox but it only works with IOS, and I need something that works withe android and IOS. Not only for one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this module for Android:

https://github.com/amorican/titanium-mapbox-android

You'll need to update the Mapbox SDK to the latest version if you want any new features but it should be a good base to start off with.

Comment: I have sean this page already. But didn't figured out how to importe the model for android in titanium studio. Dou You have some tutorial how I can importe the module in titanium?

Comment: Take a look at this answer I wrote for someone a while back http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295392/2132015 this will go over how to install / import a module in Titanium.

Comment: I have extensively used this module and done way more with it. However, it is too old for what most people want to do as it is only for raster maps  and updating the modules to mapbox gl android is not easy. I have used https://github.com/MatiseAms/ti-mapbox-gl but have had to change source files to get it to cooperate.