# Titanium can't find module

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am trying to use the google maps module but get the error message:

Script Error Couldn't find module: com.moshemarciano.googlemaps for architecture: i386

I installed the com.moshemarciano.googlemaps module using Titanium Studio and it looks to have been installed correctly in ~/Library/Application Support/Titanium/iPhone along with some other modules I have that work fine.

In my tiapp.xml I have:

```html
<module platform="iphone">com.moshemarciano.googlemaps</module>
```

In my app.js I have:

```js
fb = require('facebook');
googleMapsAPI = require('com.moshemarciano.googlemaps');
```

The require for 'facebook' works fine but the require for 'com.moshemarciano.googlemaps' causes an error.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you can follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840075/3419997) and use map module from [here](http://gitt.io/component/ti.map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `tiapp.xml` contains a reference to `com.moshemarciano.googlemaps`

```
<modules>
    ....
    <module platform="android">com.moshemarciano.googlemaps</module>
    ....
</modules>
```

Comment: Thanks Funtik. There is such a reference but it turns out it should be googleMaps rather than googlemaps! So all good now