# can't find module: ti.imagefactory for architecture x86_64

Tags: module, 64-bit, titanium, x86-64, appcelerator

I keep getting the following error.

> can't find module: ti.imagefactory for architecture x86_64).

I have followed every suggested answer I could possibly find on the net, including editing the manifest file, editing the module setting in Xcode, copy the URL straight from the download link and pasting it into titaniums module insert. It appears in tiapp.xml but still nothing.

I must add that this happens with all modules I'm using from GitHub, so I'm assuming that if I solve this problem once, I should then be able to replicate the solution for them all. This how now held up my app development at this stage until I can resolve this issue and is really frustrating, I would appreciate if anyone had any clear concise proven solutions.

Comment: Please show your tiapp.xml

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The whole doc is too large to enter so I have pasted the bottom half of tiapp.xml which I thought holds more necessary data in regards to the question

Comment: <modules>
        <module platform="iphone">ti.imagefactory</module>
        <module platform="iphone">com.appcelerator.urlSession</module>
        <module platform="iphone">dk.napp.social</module>
        <module platform="android">ti.cloudpush</module>
        <module platform="commonjs">ti.cloud</module>
        <module platform="android">facebook</module>
        <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
    </modules>
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">true</target>

Comment: <target device="iphone">true</target>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>3.5.1.GA</sdk-version>
    <plugins>
        <plugin version="1.0">ti.alloy</plugin>
    </plugins>
    <modules>
        <!-- Add the appropriate line(s) to your modules section -->
        <module platform="android">facebook</module>
        <module platform="iphone">facebook</module>
    </modules>

Comment: according to imagefactory module at [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/component/ti.imagefactory); this module supports x86_64 architecture; maybe try to re-install module properly using [steps here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27840075/3419997).