# Ti_Keychain module compilation

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator, keychain

I want to use TiKeychain for Appcelerator. I download the module from here (https://github.com/pegli/ti_keychain).

When I try to compile, this error appear:

```
> [ERROR] :  2015-08-05 12:56:15.779 xcodebuild[56074:256307] [MT]
> DVTAssertions: Warning in
> /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-7720/IDEFoundation/SourceControl/Model/IDESourceControlManager.m:423
> [ERROR] :  Details:  Error
> Domain=com.apple.dt.IDESourceControlErrorDomain Code=-1 "Missing
> extension: public.vcs.subversion" UserInfo=0x7fa2d6173b60
> {NSLocalizedDescription=Missing extension: public.vcs.subversion}
> [ERROR] :  Object:   <IDESourceControlManager: 0x7fa2d47bba40> [ERROR]
> :  Method:   -loadRepositories [ERROR] :  Thread:   <NSThread:
> 0x7fa2d1c0b7c0>{number = 1, name = main} [ERROR] :  Please file a bug
> at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful
> information you can provide. [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Comment: have you actually downloaded a release? Or the repository? The release is precompiled and can be easily added to your Titanium Project

Comment: easiest way is to [use gittio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27801921/titanium-module-imagefactory-wont-work/27840075#27840075) and keychain module is avail at [this link](http://gitt.io/component/com.obscure.keychain).

Comment: Thank you @turtle by this way I was be able to install the module.